# Select Image in Selenium 2.9

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, selenium-ide, finder

I'm trying to use RSpec to try and automate testing for post-maintenance weekends here where I'm interning at. I'm using Selenium WebDriver 2.9.0 to get a skelton going and then adding in personalized code. What I'm currently stuck on is trying to have the WebDriver click on an image that will then navigate to the correct HTML but I'm currently unable to do so. Here's what I have so far...

```
   it "can go to Ultratime" do
     @ie_driver.find_element(:link, "My Resources").click
     wait.until { @ie_driver.execute_script("return document.readyState;") == "complete" }
     sleep 3
     wait.until { @ie_driver.find_element(:link_text => "Login").displayed?}
       #test above line
       puts "found Ultratime"

     #this just finds the "Logout" button and clicks it
     @ie_driver.find_element(:name, "ee").click
   end
```

here's the html code pertaining to the said "button" for the site that I'm trying to navigate through:

```
<body id="ultratime-insidend" class="ultratime ultratime-insidend ">
<p id="ultratime">
<a class="single" href="#">
    <img alt="Ultratime" src="https://controller.nd.edu/stylesheets/images/logo2.gif"></img>
    Login
</a>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I should also add that the error I end up getting is a timeout error because it's "Unable to find element with link text == Login"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking on image works just like clicking on any other element. If you have problem locating image, give it `id` and use css selector i.e.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#yourimageid").click()
```

Edit: to switch focus to frame, use:

```
driver.switch_to.frame driver.find_element(..)
```

Any locator should work, if you can't set ID, like

```
drive.switch_to.frame driver.find_element( :xpath, "//iframe" )
```

Comment: unfortunately I don't have rights to add id tags. I found out that the issue is that the image is within an iframe. So the reason it's not able to find the element was because I need to shift the focus to the iframe first before I get to the element...Unfortunately I'm new to Ruby, so I've got to figure out how to set the focus to the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

> Clicking on image works just like clicking on any other element. If you have >problem locating image, give it id and use css selector i.e.
>
> ```
> driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#yourimageid").click()
> ```
>
> Edit: to switch focus to frame, use:
>
> ```
> driver.switch_to.frame driver.find_element(..)
> ```
>
> Any locator should work, if you can't set ID, like
>
> ```
> drive.switch_to.frame driver.find_element( :xpath, "//iframe" )
> ```

Thank you Borsunho, after finding out that I needed to find the iframe first it made things much simpler. This was my end result:

```
 it "can go to Ultratime", focus: true do
   @ie_driver.find_element(:link, "My Resources").click
   @ie_driver.switch_to.frame(@ie_driver.find_element(:css, 'iframe[src="https://controller.nd.edu/ultratime/insidend/"]'))
   @ie_driver.find_element(:class,"single").click
 end
```