# Clicking button with Selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec

This question is a continuation of my last question (which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613244/select-image-in-selenium-2-9)). The issue that I'm having now trying to click a logout button using Selenium. Continuing from my last post, I'm trying to switch to a new window that pops up by searching the page for the logout button. I'm having trouble actually getting Selenium to recognize that button. Here's what I have for my method:

```
it "can go to Ultratime", focus: true do
   @ie_driver.find_element(:link, "My Resources").click
   sleep 5
   @ie_driver.switch_to.frame(@ie_driver.find_element(:css, 'iframe[src="https://controller.nd.edu/ultratime/insidend/"]'))
   @ie_driver.find_element(:class,"single").click
   @window = @ie_driver.window_handles.detect { |w|
      @ie_driver.switch_to.window(w)
      wait.until { @ie_driver.find_element(:xpath, "//td[class='signbuts']") }
   }
   @ie_driver.switch_to.window(@window)
end
```

and the source code for the button that I'm trying to click:

```
<table class="table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height:20px">
        <!--hr-->
        <td class="td">
           <button id="signbut" class="signbuts" title="" onblur="buttonBlur(this)" 
           onmouseout="buttonLeave(this)" onfocus="buttonFocus(this)" 
           onmouseover="buttonHover(this)" menuitem="ATW910" 
           onclick="signclick('W' ,'LOGOUT' ,'Logout' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'ATW' ,'910' ,'' ,'' )"></button>
        </td>
        <td class="td">
           <button id="signbut" class="signbut" title="Leave the application"
           onblur="buttonBlur(this)" onmouseout="buttonLeave(this)" 
           onfocus="buttonFocus(this)" onmouseover="buttonHover(this)" menuitem="ATW900"
           onclick="signclick('D' ,'EXITSYS' ,'Quit' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'ATW' ,'900' ,'' ,'Leave the application' )">
           </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I show two different buttons just to show that I can't simply just look for the button id tag (which would make things so much easier). The error that I get when I try to run my script is a "Unable to find element "//td[class='signbuts']" " and as a result, it times out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Having the same id on one page more than once, is generally considered a defect. Have a chat with the dev.

Comment: I can't, it was developed by a third party company. I just have to make due with what I have. Everyone else who has seen the HTML code has agreed that it's incredibly stupid to have non-unique id's for elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue. Somehow when I inspected the page source, the class name for that button was "signbut**s**". When I did this:

```
puts @ie_driver.page_source
```

for that button, it returned a class name of "signbut". I don't know as to why or how the page source had changed but it did. As soon as I ran it with the new class name it ran just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample code does not have a `td` with a class name `signbuts`, as can be seen from your error.

There is a `button` with that class! However, when targeting an element by class, you should use the locator "classname". Something like:

```
@ie_driver.find_element(:classname, "signbuts")
```

Note I am not familiar with Ruby, so the syntax may be off.

Comment: You're right, the //td tag does absolutely nothing. I've tried using :class (but not :class_name yet) to no avail. Since the previous problem I had consisted of an iframe, I was wondering if there's something special you had to do with tables. I'll give :class_name a try and see how that goes.

EDIT:
@SiKing changing the syntax to :class_name did no good. It's still timing out because It can't find the element (I had added a wait.until wrapper of 30 seconds in case it was moving too quickly).